# How to use Django ORM with cloud NDB?

Tags: django, orm, google-cloud-datastore, django-orm

I am trying to create an django project in which database is handled by cloud NDB. I checked out the cloud ndb documentation [here](https://googleapis.dev/python/python-ndb/latest/index.html) and it only specifies the middleware that I need to include in my settings.py file. I want to use django ORM facility but I don't know how to do that with cloud NDB. I don't even know if I can use it so any answers are welcome.

Thank you for help.

Comment: I would suggest to check [Python-NDB-ORM](https://github.com/berlincode/ndb-orm). I hope this answer your question.

Comment: Thank you but i cannot figure it out still.

Comment: what is your use case? What database are you using? Can you post the code you tried and the documentation you followed?

Comment: Thanks but I was able to handle that part but got an error which I am trying to solve.
Can you help with that  ->  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61364134/cloud-ndb-middleware-for-django-notimplemented-error-how-can-i-solve-it

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use cloud NDB directly with Django ORM.